# ruby: How comes File.read in utf-8 fails to read a valid utf-8 character?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding

##### Context

- Trying to parse with `ruby 2.6.3+` a `csv` file `utf-8` encoded
- The file contains one character that throws a [`CSV::MalformedCSVError`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/MalformedCSVError.html)
- After isolating, the character of interest seems to be the *SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK* (`U+201A`). This one `‚`.
- That character seems to be supported by `UTF-8` (3 bytes, in hex: `e2809a` or `\xe2\x80\x9a`) ([ref1](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201a/charset_support.htm), [ref2](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201A))

##### `test.csv` file content

```
"value"
"abc‚d"
```

Error when parsing with `CSV` class:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'csv'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> CSV.read("test.csv", **{headers: true, skip_blanks: true, encoding: "utf-8"})
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from C:/ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:297:in `parse'
        1: from C:/ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:711:in `build_scanner'
CSV::MalformedCSVError (Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 in line 2.)
```

although `\u201a` is a `utf-8` supported character:

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "\u201a"
=> "‚"
irb(main):002:0> str.ord.to_s(16)
=> "201a"
irb(main):003:0> str.encoding.name
=> "UTF-8"
irb(main):004:0> str.unpack("H*")
=> ["e2809a"]
```

##### Treating encoding errors with `scrub`

Using [`String#scrub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scrub) with a `block` does not seem to get the *SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK*. See the code below (`x82` refers to the original `‚`):

```
irb(main):001:0> content = File.read('test.csv', encoding: 'utf-8')
=> "\"value\"\n\"abc\x82d\"\n"
irb(main):002:0> content.scrub! do |bytes|
irb(main):003:1*   "<" + bytes.unpack('H*')[0] + ">"
irb(main):004:1> end
=> "\"value\"\n\"abc<82>d\"\n"
irb(main):005:0> require 'csv'
=> true
irb(main):006:0> CSV.parse(content, **{headers: true, skip_blanks: true, encoding: "utf-8"}).each do |row|
irb(main):007:1*   pp row["value"]
irb(main):008:1> end
"abc<82>d"
=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:2>
```

As shown above, the *SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK* is replaced by `<82>`, the hexadecimal representation of the offending bytes. At this point, I am a bit lost.

##### Question

While it seems consistent that there is a `CSV::MalformatedCSVError` and that `String#scrub` fails to find the 3 bytes of the UTF-8 `e2809a` character (getting one byte instead: `0x82`):

1. If the character `\u201a` is supported by `UTF-8` (as `e2809a`), **what can be the root cause of the error?**

   - Opening the `csv` file in a text editor (Notepad++), the character is correctly displayed on the text area. When I copy and paste the character (`‚`) in [this Unicode Lookup](https://unicodelookup.com), it correctly identifies the character. So nothing seems to be wrong with it.
2. Looking at the code sample above (`irb`), nothing seems wrong with the usage of `CSV.read` and `File.read`. **Could you confirm (explain) or discard if the error is related to the usage of those methods?**

Perhaps there is nothing to fix, not to be expected, but I am not sure. It seems fairly difficult, if not impossible, to create a generic solution in `ruby` that correctly spots the offending character.

Comment: Notepad++ informs about file encoding in the [status bar](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/#:~:text=%E2%98%90-,show%20status%20bar,-%3A%20there%20will%20be)

Comment: @JosefZ yup: `UTF-8`. Well spotted, though.  I will update the question. It looks like the character shown in `Notepad++` was not the one that was meant to be. There's a diacritic character. Once I got more info I will update the question. Hopefully, this can lead to some point.

Comment: Can you show the _byte values_ of your file? (either decimal or hex)